# How can I fix a terrible bug in the middle of Botanicula?

Tags: botanicula

There is a level in the Botanicula, which you have to collect 18 birds. When I enter the biggest house (the green one) the game suddenly plays automatically by itself and I can't do anything about it (Including loading my previous save file).
I wanted to post a picture of this house, but I couldn't; however it's the house that is like a restaurant and has a chef.
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? What happens if you let it go on?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely a bug.
There is an animation that just keeps repeating. Everyone are doing their work. Sometimes the main characters just go on each other's heads to reach the bird, but that's it. It just get repeated and repeated.

Comment: Possibly relevant info: [some](http://www.gamersgate.co.uk/gametutor?issue=227572) [sources](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRpba0sHdKA) indicate some sites may have accidentally made buggy, pre-release versions of the game available for download around the time the game launched, but that this has since been fixed. Try downloading the game again, reinstall and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: This *exact* same thing happened to me, too, although it was in a different screen in Level 2. Restarting the game solved it in my case, and the game even saved my progress up to that very screen.

Answer (score 3):

The [video linked by raveturned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64275/how-can-i-fix-a-terrible-bug-in-the-middle-of-botanicula#comment90481_64275) actually shows your glitch around 1m25s:

It has the runaway animations and all. The video's details explain both the issue and the fix (emphasis mine):

> Gamersgate.com broke the official street date and released the game with an incorrect build. This meant the glitch at the end of the level was caused which locked the game from getting the final two chickens!
>
> UPDATE: FIX AVAILABLE!
> Please download the official release from botanicula net. Then uninstall and reinstall the new official download. **This fixes the kitchen area properly and you can solve the puzzle there** and then solve the puzzle with the mother and three children to get the chicken out the oven. After that go ahead and continue to the next area!

Comment: Indeed. I was hesitant to post as an answer without knowing whether the asker bought their copy on GamersGate.